# When will i get my season rewards back?

Tags: league-of-legends

So  I recently received a chat ban and lost my plat border, when I finish the chat ban will I get my rewards back?

Answer (score 4):

If it's just a bug (which is highly unlikely) you'll get your rewards pretty soon since getting chat-restricted during pre-season shouldn't take away existing rewards.

However it's possible that you are amongst the players who weren't meant to recieve the rewards. [RiotLyte made a tweet about this](https://twitter.com/RiotLyte/status/532289601092587521). (A few days = 1 month in riot time)

If you fall under the latter category you probably won't see the rewards again.